# Flink WaterMark And Triggers - Late elements not discarded on event time?

Tags: apache-flink, watermark, flink-streaming

I am somewhat confused by how Flink deals with late elements when watermarking on event time.

My understanding is that as Flink reads a stream of data, the watermark time is progressed upon seeing any data which has a larger event time than that of the current watermark. Then, any windows which cover a time strictly less than the watermark are triggered for eviction (assuming not late allowance.

However, take this minimal example:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.{TumblingEventTimeWindows}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

object EventTimeExample {

  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

  case class ExampleType(time: Long, value: Long)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Set up environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(1)
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

    // Example S3 path
    val simple = env.fromCollection(Seq(
      ExampleType(1525132800000L, 1),
      ExampleType(1525132800000L, 2) ,
      ExampleType(1525132920000L, 3),
      ExampleType(1525132800000L, 4)
    ))
      .assignAscendingTimestamps(_.time)

    val windows = simple
      .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)))
      .apply{
       (window, iter, collector: Collector[(Long, Long, String)]) => {
        collector.collect(window.getStart, window.getEnd, iter.map(_.value).toString())
      }
    }

    windows.print
    env.execute("TimeStampExample")
  }
}
```

The result of running this is:

```
(1525132800000,1525132860000,List(1, 2, 4))
(1525132920000,1525132980000,List(3))
```

However, if my understanding is correct, the `4` should not be included in the first window here, as the watermark time should be updated when the value `3` record is reached.

Now I recognise this is a trivial example, but not understanding this is making it hard to understand more complicated flows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is basically correct, but there are a few more things going on here that need to be taken into account.

First of all, you've used `assignAscendingTimestamps()`, which can only be used when the event stream is perfectly in order (by timestamp), which isn't the case here. You should see this warning when you run this application:

```
WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.timestamps.AscendingTimestampExtractor  - Timestamp monotony violated: 1525132800000 < 1525132920000
```

The other factor at work here is that an `AscendingTimestampExtractor` does not update the current Watermark for every passing stream element. This is an example of a periodic watermark generator, and it will inject a `Watermark` into the stream every *n* milliseconds, where n is defined by `ExecutionConfig.setAutoWatermarkInterval(...)`, which defaults to 200 msec. This is how event #4 sneaks into the first window.

To get the results you expect, you could implement a punctuated watermark generator configured to generate a watermark for every event:

```
class PunctuatedAssigner extends AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks[ExampleType] {
  override def extractTimestamp(element: ExampleType, previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = {
    element.time
  }

  override def checkAndGetNextWatermark(lastElement: ExampleType, extractedTimestamp: Long): Watermark = {
    new Watermark(extractedTimestamp)
  }
}
```

which you would then use like this:

```
val simple = env.fromCollection(Seq(
  ExampleType(1525132800000L, 1),
  ExampleType(1525132800000L, 2) ,
  ExampleType(1525132920000L, 3),
  ExampleType(1525132800000L, 4)
))
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new PunctuatedAssigner)
```

Now your example produces these results:

```
(1525132800000,1525132860000,List(1, 2))
(1525132920000,1525132980000,List(3))
```

Event #4 has been dropped because it is late. This could be adjusted by relaxing the watermark generator so as to accommodate some amount of out-of-orderness. E.g.,

```
override def checkAndGetNextWatermark(lastElement: ExampleType, extractedTimestamp: Long): Watermark = {
  new Watermark(extractedTimestamp - 200000)
}
```

which then produces these results:

```
(1525132800000,1525132860000,List(1, 2, 4))
(1525132920000,1525132980000,List(3))
```

Or you could configure the windows to allow late events

```
val windows = simple
  .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)))
  .allowedLateness(Time.seconds(200))
  ...
```

which then causes the first window to fire twice:

```
(1525132800000,1525132860000,List(1, 2))
(1525132800000,1525132860000,List(1, 2, 4))
(1525132920000,1525132980000,List(3))
```

Note that since processing Watermarks imposes some overhead, you wouldn't normally want to use punctuated watermarks in this way (with a Watermark for every event). For most applications, periodic watermarks based on a `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` is a better choice.

Comment: Wow thanks for your detailed answer. I don't see that warning, because I've actually turned warnings off at the start of the code I posted :-)
However - if the event "4" really is late, does this warning apply?

I''m still a little bit lost on the best way to handle the more complicated case I have, but I'll move that to the mailing list. Your explanation helps a lot.

Comment: Yes, the warning applies. The ascending timestamps watermark generator is not intended to be used in cases where the timestamps aren't ascending.

Comment: By "not intended" do you mean it will actually misbehave? I couldn't tell if this would actually cause the watermark to go back in time.

Comment: The watermark will not go back in time; the implementation is protected against that. But I don't believe the exact behavior of how out-of-order events will be processed (or not) is specified, or guaranteed to remain the same.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'm a bit confused by this. From what I could see in the source code it just takes the timestamp and extracts it, but I'll keep digging to understand.

Answer (score 0):

IF BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor is used the last calculation is not outputted till a new event comes. If we use SystemTime in the watermark it works but when you re-run for messages with embedded timestamp (past events) it does not calculate for those.